# How to call a store procedure inside a do-while loop in vba access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba

I have been working on passing store procedures in different scenarios. Currently, I am trying to call a SP via pass-through query inside the do-while loop. I have a SP named `usp_MovePending` and a pass-through query `qryPending`. I have a code with do-while loop in which I have to call the SP.

```vb
Public Sub Import()

On Error Resume Next

Dim DB As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim UserStr As String
Dim ROG As Date
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim sql As String

UserStr = sqlfixup(CurrentUser())
Set DB = CodeDb
Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from tblQty where materialid <> 0")
DoCmd.Hourglass True
Set qdf = DB.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = SQLConnectString
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True

Do While rs.EOF = False
    With MatManagement.Transactions
        .BeginTransaction
        .TransactionClassID = 1
        .MaterialID = rs!MaterialID
        .TransactionCreateUser = CurrentUser()
        .TransactionDate = Date
        .CommitTransaction

        If .Failure <> True Or .TransactionID <> 0 Then
          CodeDb.Execute "update tblMMTransactions set transNote = '" & sqlfixup(rs.Fields("note")) & "' where transactionid = " & .TransactionID, dbSeeChanges
        End If

        With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPending")
          .sql = "exec usp_MovePending @materialid=" & rs!MaterialID & ",@SysUser=" & " '" & UserStr & "'" & "," & " @ROG=getdate()" & ",@force= 1"
          .Execute
        End With

    End With        
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
qdf.Close
DB.Close
DoCmd.Hourglass False    
End Sub
```

In above code, I had added few lines of code in the old code which is shown as below:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPending")
          .sql = "exec usp_MovePending @materialid=" & rs!MaterialID & ",@SysUser=" & " '" & UserStr & "'" & "," & " @ROG=getdate()" & ",@force= 1"
          .Execute
End With
```

When I debug my code, it retrieves the SP's parameter to pass-through query. But, I think my code is not calling SP (when I test SP by itself, it works just fine). I think SQL is waiting for some return values but Access is not returning anything. I tried different approaches but while researching many developers recommend to use this approach. Can anyone point out what I am missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referencing the SP in VB rather than SQL?

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPending")
          .sql = "exec " & usp_MovePending & " @materialid=" & rs!MaterialID & ",@SysUser=" & " '" & UserStr & "'" & "," & " @ROG=getdate()" & ",@force= 1"
          .Execute
End With
```

What result does this give you?

Is the SP a global variable that the SQL can see? can you easily call it within the access query builder into a field? Or is it only seen by the VB code within a procedure?

Comment: Yes, I had tried referencing SP in VB, but I wasn't being able to get materialID from the form so used this approach. I am not sure what you mean SP global or not. My SP is in SQL so ya SQL can see it.

Comment: If you add fixed values to your "qryPending" and open the query does it return values? If not have you checked that the parameter names are the same as your SP has defined, Access seems a little strange about having to use the same parameter names as defined in the SP.
Also try using **dbo.usp_MovePending**